# Times p map in Bockstein (Quite confused)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

[image]

The following is from McCleary's book pg 461.

Q1) I am confused about the map $$-\times p^{r-1}:H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z})\to H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z})$$

Just one page earlier, I saw this map $-\times p: H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\to H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$.

Why for one map, the domain and the codomain is the same (both same powers of $p$) , while for the other map the domain and codomain are different ($H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$?

Q2) I am also confused about the map $p^{r-1}H_n(X)\xrightarrow{-\times p}p^{r-1}H_n(X)$. How does it work? If we multiply some element in $p^{r-1}H_n(X)$ by $p$, shouldn't it go to $pH_n(X)$?

Thanks for any help!

(Previous page 460)
[image]

Comment: 1) I think that is just McCleary's notation. Both maps have the same action on elements, $a\mapsto pa$, but different domains. The first map is true multiplication by $p$, whilst the second is really the subgroup inclusion. You can check that each of the maps is well-defined.

Comment: 2) Don't forget that $p^rx=p^{r-1}(px)$. That is $p^rH_n(X)\subseteq p^{r-1}H_n(X)$. You can think of the given map as the composite $p^{r-1}H_n(X)\xrightarrow{\times p} p^rH_n(X)\subseteq p^{r-1}H_n(X)$.

Comment: I see. If $[\alpha]\in H_n(X)$, then $[p\alpha]$ is also in $H_n(X)$. Thanks.